# How can I add a shadow to all of the views inside of my TableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, shadow

I have a table view being used as a "News Feed". Each cell has a few views and labels. I need some of the views to have a drop shadow. How can this be achieved?

Oh and I'm using Swift

Answer (score 0):

For example subclass your cells view and implement:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
    CGContextSetShadow(currentContext, CGSizeMake(-15, 20), 5);
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using swift

Comment: Should be pretty much the same in Swift, though. If you know both languages, you should be able to translate the code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a quick shadow is to set the `shadowOpacity` property.  See if this meets your needs:

```
myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
```

You'll find there are a handful of other shadow properties, such as setting color, offset, radius, etc, as noted in the [CALayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowOpacity).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CALayer` properties:

```
 let label = UILabel()
 label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
 label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
 label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
```